# Java - NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a toggle button (F) to hide or show my chat area (JTextArea) which is on a JScrollPane (sp) and it's not working...

Here is what I do...

I have it set as public...

`public JScrollPane sp;`

and I set it inside the `init()` like this:
`JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(c);`

`c` is the JTextArea....

```
 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F)
{
    if (sp.isVisible())
    {
        sp.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        sp.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tileGen.keyPressed(tileGen.java:522)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is line 522: `if (sp.isVisible()) {`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why there are two declarations of sp ?

public `JScrollPane sp;`

`JScrollPane sp` = new JScrollPane(c);

Comment: So that he can ask a question on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Oh, I think I should be taking out JScrollPane out of JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(c);!

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to set the instance variable, get rid of the `JScrollPane sp` in init()  (the line should just be `sp = new JScrollPane(c);`).  With it in, you're declaring and setting a local variable, and the object's `sp` never gets set.

Answer (score 2):

--- Edited in response to having line 522 ---

Because you have `JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(...);` you are hiding the member variable `sp` with a variable having the same name.  This means that once you leave the `init()` block the locally defined sp variable will disappear and the JScrollPane will not have been stored in the member variable `sp`.

Which leads to the following ....

You thought that the member variable `sp` was assigned to an object, but it is still null.  You need to make sure that the member variable `sp` is not null before you can call methods on it.

--- Original post follows ---

Look at line 522 of tileGen.java.  Odds are you are calling a method on an object there, like so

```
someObject.setValue(someValue);
```

the problem is that someObject isn't set to an object, it is still null.